# Java - Retrieving and Displaying Info from a JTextArea

Tags: java

I am trying to take the input string from a JTextArea and display it back to the user by putting it back in the JTextArea, so the finished product should be two identical copies of the string that the user has inputed. The program goes as far as to ask the question but it doesnt seem to either take the input or use the input to output it to the JTextArea. It would be a real help if somebody would help and direct me. ;)

```
static JFrame jf;
static JTextArea jtf;

public static void main(String[] args) {

 jtf = new JTextArea();

    jf = new JFrame();
    jf.setVisible(true);
    jf.setResizable(true);
    jf.setSize(400,400);
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jf.add(jtf);

    playerchoice = jtf.getText();
    jtf.setText(playerchoice);
    }
```

Comment: That's not how you use Swing, please [read some tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

Comment: How do you "take input" from a user and display it in the same place? Isn't that the equivalent of them just typing it in the box and leaving it there? Also, that code isn't valid.

Comment: @RyanJ As stated in the question, two identical copies should be displayed. You should use TextArea.append() which will add the text instead of replacing the current one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are drawing the value of jtf in the same text area without waiting for the user to input anything.
You need to add a key listener to the text area (listening for the enter key for example) or a button to trigger the action you want to perform (copy the text in your case)

Answer (score 0):

I think I know the answer. You're copying the text from a JTextArea, and putting it back in there. I don't see any point in doing that. Maybe make another JTextArea and display it there?